# Boot Problem [No bootable devices found]

Tags: boot, dell, laptop, devices

I have a laptop from dell and recently I reinstalled ubuntu 14.04 and when I turn the laptop on it says "No bootable devices found". I installed it through UEFI DVD.
The boot mode is set to: UEFI; Secure Boot: Off
[image: picture1]

When I try to open it trough Internal HDD, it says "`Selected boot device failed. Press any key to reboot the system.`" Guys, can you help me ?

Comment: Could you try to select "change boot mode settings" and try to boot to legacy mode?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a boot repair disk? if not I recommend going [here if you do not have a live Ubuntu USB](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)
or [here if you do have a live USB with Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) both options use the same software it's just one is available in a bootable disk version.
Please note a USB drive is recommend for today systems as most do not have a DVD drive in it